# HTTP POST Request in Java .setRequestMethod() Does Nothing

Tags: java, http, post, soundcloud

I am absolutely tearing my hair out over this one.

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request in Java, but it keeps sending it as a GET instead. I followed several different ways to send a POST request, but all of them just end up sending as a GET.

This is what I currently have:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.close();

        // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                resp += line;
            }
            rd.close();
```

I read on one post on StackOverflow that conn.setDoOuput(true) is supposed to make the connection a POST automatically; however, when I debug through the code, the protected member conn.method stays as GET.

I also tried casting url.openConnection() as a HttpURLConnection and called .setRequestMethod("POST") on it, which did absolutely nothing to change conn.method.

As a bonus, I'm trying to do soundcloud authentication and basically every way I've thought of doing it has been an utter failure... Maybe someone has a better solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)

Comment: you can see a POST example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508606/how-to-authenticate-against-website-using-apache-httpclient-4-2-1-or

Comment: Neither of those answer my question... What in particular am I doing wong??? I have tried setting it explicitly to a "POST" method and that still doesn't work.

Comment: Use the HTTPClient library. It greatly simplifies what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using SoundCloud's Java SDK?

https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper

This should take most of the HTTP/OAuth2 away from your code.

But even if you want more control over what you are doind, it is usually a good idea to use a proper HTTP client library, like Apache's, instead of trying to fight agains the very basic Java SE support for it. Check out: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: Yea I checked out the wrapper, I just wanted to see if I could do the oauth stuff myself. I'll probably just end up going that route now anyways since I'm trying to get this done asap. Any idea why the setRequestMethod("POST") does not work? This seems so simple, yet it does not work... frustrating >:(